# Why does putting jQuery code does not work sometime when placed inside <head> tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I often find myself in a place where even a simple jQuery code like below -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("input[type='text']").click(function () {
        this.select();
    });
});
```

Does not work when placed inside "head" tag, but moving this snippet just before the end of body tag in master page works fine. Is there any basic JavaScript/jQuery principle which I am missing.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Adding your **jquery.js** before writing your script in the header tag should do the trick!!
Also,check for the errors on console using firebug or other developer tools.

Comment: your jquery file is not inserted properly

Comment: When you create new elements on page with JS/jQuery methods .click(), .change() etc. doesn't work. You have to trigger them with .on() or .live()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons, just some of which are:

- You are loading the `jquery.js` file after this block of code - Solution is to move your code below the link to the file
- Although `.ready()` almost guarantees that the code within it will fire only after the `document` has completed loading, there is still the possibility that the text element you are trying to select may not be ready/loaded yet - Solution here is to use the `.on()` method: `jQuery("input[type='text']").on('click', function () {...}));`

Answer (score -1):

I ran into similar issues in the past where a scipt wouldn't always fire on elements that weren't ready.

Try using `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`.